# Only the First Record is Displayed When Retrieving from SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

"I have multiple  records in Shared Preferences, and I've created a table using the Table class. My goal is to display these records in a table format with name, email, and score, but the code is not working correctly,It's showing only the first record How can i fix this problem.Thank in advance.....

this is Shared Preferences  file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
    <string name="flutter.User_aaa_name">aaa</string>
    <string name="flutter.User_uuu_email">digrev@gmail.com</string>
    <string name="flutter.User_aaa_score">5</string>
    <string name="flutter.User_uuu_score">0</string>
    <string name="flutter.User_uuu_name">uuu</string>
    <string name="flutter.User_uuu_password">123</string>
    <string name="flutter.User_aaa_email">digrev@gmail.com</string>
    <string name="flutter.User_aaa_password">123</string>
</map>
```

And this is  my code to display data in table

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
class MyTable extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyTableState createState() => _MyTableState();
}

class _MyTableState extends State<MyTable> {
  List<User> users = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Shared Preferences'tan bütün kayıtları al
    _getUsersData();
  }

  Future<void> _getUsersData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   // print(prefs.getKeys().map((e) => e.runtimeType) );
    List<String> keys = prefs.getKeys().toList();
   // print(keys );
    List<Object> userDataList = [];
    for (String key in keys) {
      Object? userData = prefs.get(key);
      userDataList.add(userData!);
    }
print(userDataList);
    {
      users.add(User(
        name: userDataList[0].toString(),
        score: userDataList[1].toString(),
        email: userDataList[2].toString(),
      ));
      print("length " + users.length.toString());
    }
    setState(() {}); // Yeni verileri göstermek için setState kullanın.
  }




  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Tüm Kayıtları Göster'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Table(
          border: TableBorder.all(),
          children: [
            TableRow(
              children: [
                TableCell(
                  child: Center(child: Text('Adı')),
                ),
                TableCell(
                  child: Center(child: Text('Puanı')),
                ),
                TableCell(
                  child: Center(child: Text('E-posta')),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            for (User user in users)
              TableRow(
                children: [
                  TableCell(
                    child: Center(child: Text(user.name)),
                  ),
                  TableCell(
                    child: Center(child: Text(user.score)),
                  ),
                  TableCell(
                    child: Center(child: Text(user.email)),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class User {
  final String name;
  final String score;
  final String email;

  User({
    required this.name,
    required this.score,
    required this.email,
  });
}
```

Comment: Do you have the output to `print(userDataList)`? Does the list have more than one element?

Comment: Hi,this  code ->print(userDataList) gives this the output      [aaa, digrev@gmail.com, 4, 0, bbb, 123, digrev@gmail.com, 333]   there are2 records but funny that this line of code  print("length " + users.toString());   gives me this output  [User{name: aaa, score: digrev@gmail.com, email: 4}].I think this the source of proplem